# How to set up a has_many relation in Rails for two different types of relation between two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

Here's my schema:

```
Participant = 
   id: int
   user_id: int
   program_id: int
   ... other fields
end

User = 
   id: int
   name: text
   ... other fields
end

Program = 
   id: int
   user_id:  int # this is the manager of the program
end
```

So, in English:

- Users are people.
- A program is managed by a user.
- A program also has a set of participants, each of which is a user

And so in Rails:

```
class Participant
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to
end

class User
   has_many :programs
   has_many :participants
end

class Program
   has_many :participants
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Notice that a user really has_many programs, the ones that they manage, as well as has_many programs through participants, which is all the programs that they participate in.

What I want is to be able to say:

- a_user.manages_programs
- a_user.participates_in_programs

So two flavors of user has_many programs. I need to do some magic combination of :through, :as, :class, or something along those lines but I can't figure it out so far.

One additional question continuing this example. I now have

```
class User
  has_many :participations, class_name: "Participant"
  has_many :moderated_programs, class_name: "Program", foreign_key: 'moderator_id'
  has_many :participating_programs, through: :participations, class_name: "Program", source: :program
end

class Participant
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :program
end
```

Notice the third line. What I want is to take advantage of this series of associations: a participant has a user_id and a program_id. I would like to be able to say u1.participating_programs and get a list of one or more programs this user participates in, but the above is not working. Can you tell where I am off base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Charles, you have some wording/language issues that are confusing things. Participations may be a better term. I wouldn't recommend polymorphic here - the user may have two different roles, but the users won't be of a different type.  Especially if it's possible for a manager to also be a participant...

```
class User
  has_many :participations
  has_many :programs, through: :participations
  has_many :managed_programs, class_name: 'Program'
end

class Program
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, through: :participations
end

# Just a join table.  Nothing special
class Participation
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :program
end
```

Comment: nice refinement and I think you answer my follow up to Charles

Comment: He does! :-) You should accept his answer, it shows you everything you need.

Comment: How does 'has_many :managed_programs, class_name: 'Program'' know that the foreign key that it should look at in Program is called 'user_id'?  Because that clause is found in 'class User'? So if for accuracy I wanted to change the foreign key in Program to be 'manager_id' then what would I have to do? 'has_many :managed_programs, class_name: 'Program', foreign_key: 'manager_id'?

Comment: I believe it tries a few cues to figure out the foreign key if it's not given explicitly.  Adding foreign_key: 'manager_id' should do it.

Answer (score 1):

First off, just a language thing: I don't think a user has many participants. He *is* a participant or he *is* the manager of a program. So he rather has many participations.

You can write this as follows:

```
class User
    has_many :participations, class_name: "Participant"
    has_many :managed_programs, class_name: "Program"
end
```

Also, at least in your code above, the Participant class is missing

```
belongs_to :user
```

Since it appears that you need to differentiate between two different types of users, the `polymorphic` functionality would come in handy. Then you don't need an extra participant table. [See here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: Thanks! are those typos or am I missing something? shouldnt "class:"  be "class_name:" ? and ":participant" be "Participant" ?

Comment: Ok this looks good. Followup: I would like to get a set of programs that this user participates in, so from user -> participant -> program. Is that a 'through' and how would I express that?